# Eloquent updateOrCreate error: General error: 1364 Field doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am trying to use the updateOrCreate function and it was working earlier however when I added a new row called `user` it has stopped working even though my updateOrCreate look like this:

```
SystemCoreStats::updateOrCreate(['id' => $systemId],['type' => $type, 'stat_build_store' => $val, 'user' => $user->id]);
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Added user to the database? Did you update your model to reflect the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this error means the `user` that your trying to `updateOrCreate` doesn't exist.

try to check in your Model if this is present:

```
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = [
   'column_name',
   'column_name',
   'column_name',
];
```

in your case

```
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = [
   'type',
   'stat_build_store',
   'user',
];
```

and try to check in your db if the column exist.

Can you post more of your code?

Comment: That was perfect I forgot about the model protected field needed updating.